# Listing sql data in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to list all the Members in my database on a grid through a list. I don't know if I'm in the right track.

I'm using this :

```
        public List<Member> Members()
        {
            List<Member> list = new List<Member>();

            string SelectMembers = "SELECT * FROM Members";

            using (sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SelectMembers, sqlConnection))
            {

            }

            return list;
        }
```

But "IF" I'm on the right track... in the `using` section, I don't really know what to do... I'm not asking for code, but I want someone to tell me what I should do. Thanks :)

Comment: here is documentation and working example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx
Although, I see that you're using sql2008r2, so it looks like you have access to quite new technologies, why not to use ORM, like entity framework/nhibernate?

Comment: @Giedrius, though your suggestion is great but looks like OP is new to C#. So, basic way would be better as suggested by Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a code example it's easier:

```
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SelectMembers, sqlConnection)) {
    // fetch data and iterate through results
    var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) { 
        // create an object, set its properties and add it to the return list
        Member member = new Member();
        member.SomeProperty = reader["MY_COLUMN"];
        list.Add(member);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could use LINQ to SQL, there's a great tutorial on Scott Gu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`using` is a good place to start.  What I would do is then loop through the result set assigning the `properties` of the `Member` class with the columns from the dataset.  You have a variety of options when you want to read through your data.  You can use `DataSet`, `DataTable` or `SqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

With sqlcommand try to bind datareader object and than loop into this datareader to bind your list something like

```
while (objDataReader.Read())
                {
                    objM = new Member();

                    if(objDataReader["Id"] != DBNull.Value)
                        objM.Id = Convert.ToInt32(objDataReader["Id"]);

                    list.Add(objM );
                }

             return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1.aspx) to query this data.

```
DataSet members = new DataSet();
ufing(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
{
    adapter.Fill(members, "Members");
    //Fill your list there from the DataSets's DataTable
}
```

Comment: Well I thought about it, but I don't like to use tableAdapter (and I've been told it creates some conflicts inside the program) neither am I allowed. Thank's anyway :)